# Token generation system in py3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I've created a system to generate tokens that could potentially be used in some sort of program:

```
# _gen.py is simply to generate the tokens, not to check them.

import string, secrets, random

# String is for getting all ascii letters and digits.
# Secrets is for a cryptographically secure function to choose chars.
# Random is providing a random number generator.

# Base functions used to generate a token

def _tknFrag(length: int=32):
    """Generates a tknFrag, or Token Fragment."""
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(length))

def _tknFragLen():
    """Returns the tknFrag's tknFragLen, or Token Fragment Length, an int in between 30 and 34"""
    return int(random.randint(30, 34))

def _insDot(tknFrag: str):
    """Inserts a dot in the tknFrag at the end"""
    tknFrag += "."
    return tknFrag

def _insDash(tknFrag: str):
    """Inserts a dash in the tknFrag at the end"""
    tknFrag += "-"
    return tknFrag

def _ins(tknFrag: str):
    """Inserts a dash or a dot inside of the tknFrag"""
    return {
        "0" : lambda frag: _insDot(tknFrag=frag),
        "1" : lambda frag: _insDash(tknFrag=frag)
    }[str(random.randint(0, 1))](tknFrag)

# Now on to actually generating the tokens

# This is one last helper function, completely generating a fragment
def tokenFragment(repetition):
    """Generates a fragment with the random length, and the dot/dash. The repetition is to determine wether or not to actually put the dot/dash at the end of the token."""
    return _ins(_tknFrag(length=_tknFragLen())) if repetition != 2 else _tknFrag(length=_tknFragLen())

def token():
    """Generates a three-fragment-long token"""
    return "".join([tokenFragment(repetition) for repetition in range(3)])

# Gotta test it somehow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(token())
```

Here are five results from running the code:

```
2dD0ZYjV4AOGMzZ2lIg6wVPzwpB82Z.BsX34AaWpvJ7i6jtWzYI1zNRjz2pI0.GRW9Uhfl9P8Xu7pYzoSYutEwuhqjhQnN
```

```
AghhjknBMqgKLpD6rR90iXKj2yuT44B.CAyXZJtAE62L97SZUbadGBmXTTSflC9th.RbuKtUDWxQ9ROgwo2OkKYEozHc1ToRz8Q
```

```
5sFE1npNyEA7JCz9hHEJFwmP2aX4CY3p.RMiKkilzUp7kmJCigrB6HfOVPkWmsczJ-4DF3qLuQSgdwmRxiOMBLUw1ZLj1Al7n
```

```
6FCXlDGWjAKylt5rZFYxOfLecxyyL4Pj-0MGu0B2knedbR8HnFI16gHChWZ8uldQ.chCVuFycHPJXF2tj9wR3mi4W4yuRp3o
```

```
rEAi9Rn1lXNkMett8wHXLF0iJLQHbc6lI.ksViH35sOlIwFfvOjVHlyXfMS0Ye58diZB-jEX93wyHTRznkYUJvbADmOrdZZF2D0R0
```

**Note that the dots and dashes are for looks only and serve no purpose.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the first place I have a question as to why you would need this specific pattern of tokens; it seems for a very specific use case.

Secondly, you use a pretty consistent naming convention in your code (which is very good), but the shortened names and abbreviations make it difficult for a person to understand your code quickly (in my opinion).

---

Lastly, if you are  looking for less code and more speed with the same functionality, I can propose this:

```
import random
import secrets
import string

FRAGMENT_ALPHABET = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR_OPTIONS = ('.', '-')
FRAGMENT_MIN_LENGTH = 30
FRAGMENT_MAX_LENGTH = 34

def _generate_fragment(length: int, prepend_separator: bool):
    prefix = ''
    if prepend_separator:
        prefix = secrets.choice(FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR_OPTIONS)

    s = ''.join(
        secrets.choice(FRAGMENT_ALPHABET)
        for _ in range(length))

    return prefix + s

def token(num_parts: int = 3):
    return ''.join(
        _generate_fragment(
            length=random.randint(FRAGMENT_MIN_LENGTH, FRAGMENT_MAX_LENGTH),
            prepend_separator=i > 0)          # only False for the first fragment
        for i in range(num_parts))
```

In this code:

- In my opinion (opinions can be very subjective) the code is still readable, but has less functions and those have explicit long names, which helps users to understand it faster.
- I also put some general parameters as uppercase module variables at the top of the file; this makes it easier to modify and (in my opinion) also easier to read/understand in the code.
- The execution time is less. Comparing the two versions using `timeit` like this for both versions (with `Ubuntu` and `Python3.6`):

  ```
  >>> timeit.timeit('token()', 'from __main__ import token', number=10000)
  ```

  I get these results, showing my version as faster using about 8 % less time:

  ```
  Version    Time      Time comparisson
  yours      2.222258   100.0 %
  mine       2.060732    92.7 %
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Although, the shortened names were not designed to be used by the user. They were designed to be used by the `_ins` and `token` functions.